# Starting a http post after all files are uploaded with a mergeMap

Tags: angular, rxjs, webapi, mergemap

I am trying to make `POST` request after all files are uploaded. In my web form, the user can add many files to upload. I have two APIs that handle my request.

One API for my `fileupload` which saves the file in the database and returns an id (document id), and the second API saves the dossier. Before I call the `savedossier` API, I have to add all documents ids to the dossier object.

I upload the files with mergeMap:

```js
const fileupload$ = from(this.attachments).pipe(
  mergeMap(file => this.http.post<Attachement>(`${this.addAttUrl}`, file)),
);

fileupload$.subscribe(
  (data) => this.dossier.attachments.push(data),
  (err) => console.error('err: ' + err)
);

const savedossier$ = this.http.post<Dossier>(`${this.adddossierUrl}`, this.dossier);

savedossier$.subscribe(
  (data) => console.log('Dossier saved!'),
  (err) => console.error('err: ' + err)
);
```

My problem is the second call (to `savedossier$`) does not wait until all files are uploaded (because it's async). So the document id's are not added to my dossier object.

I had tested with a "ugly" solution like this:

```js
const fileupload$ = from(this.attachments).pipe(
  mergeMap(file => this.http.post<Attachement>(`${this.addAttUrl}`, file)),
);

fileupload$.subscribe(
  (data) => onuploaded(data),
  (err) => console.error('err: ' + err)
);

onuploaded(data) {
  this.dossier.attachments.push(data)
  if (this.dossier.attachments.length === this.attachments.length) {
    savedossier$.subscribe(
      (data) => console.log('Dossier saved!'),
      (err) => console.error('err: ' + err)
    );
  }
}

const savedossier$ = this.http.post<Dossier>(`${this.adddossierUrl}`, this.dossier);
```

This solution with an if statement that compares the array lengths works. But I think it is not a recommended way.

Is there a better solution from rxjs?

Comment: why don't you check when the upload is complete and from there you do what you need? you can filter events and check upload progress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right, you need first to complete all the ***fileupload*** operations before saving the document, which has to contain all the `id`s returned by the ***fileupload*** operations.

I assume also that `this.attachments` is some sort of array containing the names of the attachments.

If all this is true, I would proceed like this.

First I would create an array of Observables, each representing the http call you want to make to save an attachment and receive its `id` as response

```
const saveAttachments = this.attachments).map(
  file => this.http.post<Attachement>(`${this.addAttUrl}`, file),
);
```

You can then execute all these observables in parallel using `forkJoin` like this

```
forkJoin(saveAttachments)
```

which returns an Observable which emits when all the observables passed as parameter in the `saveAttachments` array have completed. The value emitted is an array with all the `id`s returned.

Now you can execute the last operation, i.e. save the dossier, concatenating the `savedossier$` observable to the one returned by the above `forkJoin`. The final code would look like this

```
const saveAttachments = this.attachments).map(
  file => this.http.post<Attachement>(`${this.addAttUrl}`, file),
);
forkJoin(saveAttachment).pipe(
   concatMap(ids => {
      this.dossier.attachments.push(data);
      return this.http.post<Dossier>(`${this.adddossierUrl}`, this.dossier);
   })
)
```

Note that you have to use the `concatMap` operator to specify that you want to execute the observable returned by the function passed as parameter to `concatMap` **after** the previous observable, i.e. that returned by `forkJoin`, has completed.

If you want to see some patterns on how to use Observables to compose http calls in different use cases, [this article may be of interest](https://medium.com/better-programming/rxjs-patterns-emerging-from-stackoverflow-asynchronous-api-calls-as-streams-in-the-real-world-ef636c9af19a).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) and [tap](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap) operators:

```js
const fileAndSaveDossier$ = from(this.attachments).pipe(
  mergeMap(file => this.http.post<Attachement>(`${this.addAttUrl}`, file)),
  tap(data => this.dossier.attachments.push(data)),
  switchMap(() => this.http.post<Dossier>(`${this.adddossierUrl}`, this.dossier)),
);

fileAndSaveDossier$.subscribe(
  (data) => console.log('Dossier saved!'),
  (err) => console.error('err: ' + err)
);
```

A nice video explaining `switchMap()`:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6lKoLwGlglE

I am also not sure why are you using `mergeMap()`.
You can just do it as the following:

```js
const fileAndSaveDossier$ = this.http.post<Attachement>(
  `${this.addAttUrl}`, this.attachments
).pipe(
  tap(data => this.dossier.attachments.push(data)),
  switchMap(() => this.http.post<Dossier>(`${this.adddossierUrl}`, this.dossier)),
);
```